# How to count actors of a certain type active at a certain time in an akka system?

Tags: java, scala, akka

Does Akka 2 provide a way to determine the number of actors of a certain type active at a certain time in the system?

I've was looking for something like

```
int actorCount = getContext().count(MyActor.class)
```

OR

```
Props props = Props.create(MyActor.class, "actorName")
...
int actorCount = getContext().count(props)
```

OR

```
getContext().actorSelection("/path/to/actor").count()
```

I've just started playing with the akka framework in Java, so please bear with me.

Comment: processing or waiting for message

Comment: Counting that would mean the ability to "stop the world" and then to traverse the entire Actor tree (on multiple potential nodes) and then inspect their type and report back. Could you tell me what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to shutdown the system when there is no worker (actor of a certain type) left.

Comment: Why not just hook the lifecycle methods (preStart, preRestart, postStop) on those actors and have it feed an event into the event bus that another actor can listen on and keep counts and then shutdown the system if the count ever drops to 0.

Comment: That's easy, create an actor that will be the parent of all workers of a certain type, and have it use Death Watch on all its children and then it can check if it has no children left and then exit.

Comment: DeathWatch works, but I would have preferred not to use have a stateless actor. This pattern assumes holding a form of state.

Comment: On topic, counting the number of actors of a certain type can be done by sending a "head count" message, holding an ActorRef list, passing each actor. Then each target actor can add it's ActorRef to that list and forward the message. But this depends on the nature of the system and works only if you know beyond any doubt that you don't have any actors spawning up during the "head count".

Answer (score 0):

In one of my Akka applications (my first, and not one I'd hold up as a shining example of how to write such systems), I implement a low-water / high-water work generation strategy driven by a heartbeat. The low and high water marks are defined in terms of number of work actors active, each of which does one thing and is created by a manager. That manager keeps track of started and as-yet unompleted workers and can respond to requests from the work generator for the current activity count. The response to these inquiries provides the information as to whether work in progress has fallen below the low-water mark and new work should be generated.

It's kind of crude and in a new system I'm working on now the connections between work generation and work execution, as well as checkpoint logging, is done in a more continuous, less "batch-oriented" manner. This system is about to be deployed, so at the moment I can't say for certain how it will perform, but I'm pretty sure it will exhibit better behavior than the earlier system. It's also inherently more complicated that the earlier system in how it generates, performs and records the work it does.

Answer (score 0):

[Going to put this also as a valid answer]

If the actor who needs the count is not the parent and/or cannot retrieve the `ActorRef`s of the target actors, then the following might be an alternative.

Counting the number of actors of a certain type can be done by sending a "head count" message, holding an `ActorRef` array, passing each actor. Then each target actor can add it's ActorRef to that list and forward the message. But this depends on the nature of the system and works only if you know beyond any doubt that you don't have any actors spawning up during the "head count".