# Akka references increasing constantly with Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, akka

I have changed all my multi-thread actions in my application to Akka a few weeks ago.
However, since it seems that I am starting to run out of Heap space (after a week or so).

By basically looking at all actors with

```
ActorSelection selection = getContext().actorSelection("/*");
```

the number of actors seems to increase all the time. After an hour of running I have more then 2200. They are called like:

```
akka://application/user/$Aic
akka://application/user/$Alb
akka://application/user/$Alc
akka://application/user/$Am
akka://application/user/$Amb
```

I also noticed that when opening websockets (and closing them) there are these:

```
akka://application/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-2/flow-21-0-unnamed
akka://application/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-2/flow-2-0-unnamed
akka://application/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-2/flow-27-0-unnamed
akka://application/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-2/flow-23-0-unnamed
```

Is there something specific that I need to do to close them and let them be cleaned?

I am not sure the memory issue is related, but the fact that there seem so many after an hour on the production server it could be.

[EDIT: added the code to analyse/count the actors]

```
public class RetrieveActors extends AbstractActor {

    private String identifyId;
    private List<String> list;

    public RetrieveActors(String identifyId) {
        Logger.debug("Actor retriever identity: " + identifyId);
        this.identifyId = identifyId;
    }

    @Override
    public Receive createReceive() {
        Logger.info("RetrieveActors");
        return receiveBuilder()
                .match(String.class, request -> {
                    //Logger.info("Message: " + request + " " + new Date());
                    if(request.equalsIgnoreCase("run")) {
                        list = new ArrayList<>();
                        ActorSelection selection = getContext().actorSelection("/*");
                        selection.tell(new Identify(identifyId), getSelf());
                        //ask(selection, new Identify(identifyId), 1000).thenApply(response -> (Object) response).toCompletableFuture().get();
                    } else if(request.equalsIgnoreCase("result")) {
                        //Logger.debug("Run list: " + list + " " + new Date());
                        sender().tell(list, self());
                    } else {
                        sender().tell("Wrong command: " + request, self());
                    }
                }).match(ActorIdentity.class, identity -> {
                    if (identity.correlationId().equals(identifyId)) {
                        ActorRef ref = identity.getActorRef().orElse(null);
                        if (ref != null) { // to avoid NullPointerExceptions
                            // Log or store the identity of the actor who replied
                            //Logger.info("The actor " + ref.path().toString() + " exists and has replied!");
                            list.add(ref.path().toString());
                            // We want to discover all children of the received actor (recursive traversal)
                            ActorSelection selection = getContext().actorSelection(ref.path().toString() + "/*");
                            selection.tell(new Identify(identifyId), getSelf());
                        }

                    }
                    sender().tell(list.toString(), self());
                }).build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you try https://stackoverflow.com/q/17202729/7550592 and see its count? Not sure if the number just keeps growing, or the actor come and go with increasing ID

Comment: It keeps growing, the same references are still there which were there now 1.5 hours ago. And they all respond. I will paste in the Actor I use for the analysing.